# Match multiline regex in file object

Tags: python, regex, multiline

How can I extract the groups from this regex from a file object (data.txt)?

```
import numpy as np
import re
import os
ifile = open("data.txt",'r')

# Regex pattern
pattern = re.compile(r"""
                ^Time:(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})   # Time: 12:34:56 at beginning of line
                \r{2}                       # Two carriage return
                \D+                         # 1 or more non-digits
                storeU=(\d+\.\d+)
                \s
                uIx=(\d+)
                \s
                storeI=(-?\d+.\d+)
                \s
                iIx=(\d+)
                \s
                avgCI=(-?\d+.\d+)
                """, re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

time = [];

for line in ifile:
    match = re.search(pattern, line)
    if match:
        time.append(match.group(1))
```

The problem in the last part of the code, is that I iterate line by line, which obviously doesn't work with multiline regex. I have tried to use `pattern.finditer(ifile)` like this:

```
for match in pattern.finditer(ifile):
    print match
```

... just to see if it works, but the finditer method requires a string or buffer.

I have also tried this method, but can't get it to work

```
matches = [m.groups() for m in pattern.finditer(ifile)]
```

Any idea?

---

After comment from Mike and Tuomas, I was told to use .read().. Something like this:

```
ifile = open("data.txt",'r').read()
```

This works fine, but would this be the correct way to search through the file? Can't get it to work...

```
for i in pattern.finditer(ifile):
    match = re.search(pattern, i)
    if match:
        time.append(match.group(1))
```

---

### Solution

```
# Open file as file object and read to string
ifile = open("data.txt",'r')

# Read file object to string
text = ifile.read()

# Close file object
ifile.close()

# Regex pattern
pattern_meas = re.compile(r"""
                ^Time:(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})   # Time: 12:34:56 at beginning of line
                \n{2}                       # Two newlines
                \D+                         # 1 or more non-digits
                storeU=(\d+\.\d+)           # Decimal-number
                \s
                uIx=(\d+)                   # Fetch uIx-variable
                \s
                storeI=(-?\d+.\d+)          # Fetch storeI-variable
                \s
                iIx=(\d+)                   # Fetch iIx-variable
                \s
                avgCI=(-?\d+.\d+)           # Fetch avgCI-variable
                """, re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

file_times = open("output_times.txt","w")
for match in pattern_meas.finditer(text):
    output = "%s,\t%s,\t\t%s,\t%s,\t\t%s,\t%s\n" % (match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3), match.group(4), match.group(5), match.group(6))
    file_times.write(output)
file_times.close()
```

Maybe it can be written more compact and pythonic though....

Comment: Are you sure that `\r` is right for carriage returns? Are you on a pre-OS X Mac? Try `\n` or `(\r?\n)`.

Comment: Thanks! \n seems to give a better result.

Comment: @william: there is such a thing as `match.groups()` which you can slice to skip the first arguments, or you could do: `match.group(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.

Comment: Add `re.DOTALL` argument to make wildcards match newlines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the data from the file object into a string with `ifile.read()`

Answer (score 3):

```
times = [match.group(1) for match in pattern.finditer(ifile.read())]
```

[`finditer` yield `MatchObjects`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer). If the regex doesn't match anything `times` will be an empty list.

You can also modify your regex to use non-capturing groups for `storeU`, `storeI`, `iIx` and `avgCI`, then `pattern.findall` will contain only matched times.

Note: naming variable `time` might shadow standard library module. `times` would be a better option.

Comment: I get the correct result by checking out the match.group(n) where n goes from 1 to 6. That means the regex works. But I don't get any results from the expression You provided, only an empty list. I have tried it on a text-string, which works fine, so it's probably the ifile.read() which doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: @william: you need to post example of your subject string and probably do this in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you read the whole file into a buffer using

```
buffer = open("data.txt").read()
```

and then do a search with that?

Comment: Seems like the correct way to do it! But I still have some problems with the search though...

Comment: This solution seems to give a problem with closing the file.. Maybe it's not important to do that though :)