# python -regex match and for loop that run file line by line

Tags: python, regex, file, loops, for-loop

So I was trying to match each line of a file to a regex and I did the following:

```
import re
regex='\S+\s+(\S{6})\s+VAR'
with open('/home/jyt109/humsavar.txt') as humsavar:
    for line in humsavar:
        match=regex.search(line)
        print match.group(1)
```

Expected output is the particular 6 characters that are in each line, instead I get an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exercise.py", line 74, in <module>
    match=regex.search(line)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'search'
```

I have found out (from link below) that to match a regex to each line of a file, the file has to be first turned into a list by file.read()

[Match multiline regex in file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433648/match-multiline-regex-in-file-object)

To readdress the post, is there any simpler way to do it (preferably over 1 line instead of 2)?

```
humsavar=open('/home/jyt109/humsavar.txt')
text=humsavar.read()
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you put sample file and expected output. Like what are you searching for

Answer (score 6):

I think you may have misunderstood what that link was saying.  If matches of your regex can span multiple lines, then you need to read the file using `file.read()`.  If newlines will never be a part of a match, then you can read the file line by line and try to match each line separately.

If you want to check each line separately, you can use `file.readlines()` to get a list of lines or just iterate over the file object, for example:

```
with open('/home/jyt109/humsavar.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = regex.search(line)
```

Assuming you do still want to read the entire file contents at once, you do that on one line like this:

```
text = open('/home/jyt109/humsavar.txt').read()
```

Answer (score 3):

`.read()` does not turn a file into a list (`.readlines()` does); instead it puts the entire file into a string.

But even then you can use a regex: when compiling it with `re.MULTILINE`, the anchors `^` and `$` will match the starts and ends of individual lines:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"^Match this regex in each line$", re.MULTILINE)
>>> regex.findall(text)
```

The result will be a list of all matches.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple one-liner. I tested it on the below data file. When using regular expressions it is convenient to use the [Raw String Notation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) as I have done below. I don't know what your data file is meant to look like but I just made one up that would match the search pattern you specified.

**code**

```
import re
print re.findall(r'\S+\s+(\S{6})\s+VAR', open('/tmp/test.txt').read())
```

**output**

```
['000001', '000002', '123456']
```

**test.txt**

```
x 000001 VAR
x 000002 VAR
x 123456 VAR
```