# MemoryError in Python by searching a large file using mmap and re.findall

Tags: python, pandas, mmap, large-files, python-re

I'm looking to implement a few lines of python, using re, to firstly manipulate a string then use that string as a regex search. I have strings with `*`'s in the middle of them, i.e. `ab***cd`, with the `*`'s being any length. The aim of this is to do the regex search in a document to extract any lines that match the starting and finishing characters, with any number of characters in between. i.e. ab12345cd, abbbcd, ab_fghfghfghcd, would all be positive matches. Examples of negative matches: 1abcd, agcd, bb111cd.

I have come up with the regex of `[\s\S]*?` to input instead of the `*`'s. So I want to get from an example string of `ab***cd` to `^ab[\s\S]*?cd`, I will then use that for a regex search of a document.

I then wanted to open the file in mmap, search through it using the regex, then save the matches to file.

```
import re
import mmap 

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

def searchFile(list_txt, raw_str):
    search="^"+raw_str #add regex ^ newline operator
    search_rgx=re.sub(r'\*+',r'[\\s\\S]*?',search) #replace * with regex function

    #search file
    with open(list_txt, 'r+') as f: 
        data = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
        results = re.findall(bytes(search_rgx,encoding="utf-8"),data, re.MULTILINE)

    #save results
    f1 = open('results.txt', 'w+b')
    results_bin = b'\n'.join(results)
    f1.write(results_bin)
    f1.close()

    print("Found "+str(file_len("results.txt"))+" results")

searchFile("largelist.txt","ab**cd")
```

Now this works fine with a small file. However when the file gets larger (1gb of text) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Programming\test.py", line 27, in <module>
    searchFile("largelist.txt","ab**cd")
  File "c:\Programming\test.py", line 21, in searchFile
    results_bin = b'\n'.join(results)
MemoryError
```

Firstly - can anyone help optimize the code slightly? Am I doing something seriously wrong? I used mmap because I know I wanted to look at large files and I wanted to read the file line and by line rather than all at once (hence someone suggested mmap).

I've also been told to have a look at the pandas library for more data manipulation. Would panda's replace mmap?

Thanks for any help. I'm pretty new to python as you can tell - so appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268465/using-mmap-to-apply-regex-to-whole-file

Comment: No dup. The answer to that question helped me progress to this point.

Comment: You might indeed be able to use pandas here, but I think it depends on the structure of your data. Pandas has `pandas.Series.str.match`, which would return `True` in _cells_, that fit the regex. So in this case, each line in your doc could be a cell and you'd get a match on the lines/cells that have fit.

Comment: Hi Bertil, the data is a large text file with different strings on newlines:
```ab123
ccv444
sdads444```

like that :) - seems like SO comments won't put stuff on newlines but hopefully you can get what I mean?

Comment: Right, okay @TomOldy. Check my answer, does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? In this situation, what you want is a list of all of your lines represented as strings. The following emulates that, resulting in a list of strings:

```
import io

longstring = """ab12345cd
abbbcd
ab_fghfghfghcd
1abcd
agcd
bb111cd
"""

list_of_strings = io.StringIO(longstring).read().splitlines()
list_of_strings
```

**Outputs**

```
['ab12345cd', 'abbbcd', 'ab_fghfghfghcd', '1abcd', 'agcd', 'bb111cd']
```

This is the part that matters

```
s = pd.Series(list_of_strings)
s[s.str.match('^ab[\s\S]*?cd')]
```

**Outputs**

```
0         ab12345cd
1            abbbcd
2    ab_fghfghfghcd
dtype: object
```

Edit2: Try this: (I don't see a reason for you to want to it as a function, but I've done it like that since that what you did in the comments.)

```
def newsearch(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        list_of_strings = f.read().splitlines()
    s = pd.Series(list_of_strings)
    s = s[s.str.match('^ab[\s\S]*?cd')]
    s.to_csv('output.txt', header=False, index=False)

newsearch('list.txt')
```

**A chunk-based approach**

```
import os

def newsearch(filename):
    outpath = 'output.txt'
    if os.path.exists(outpath):
        os.remove(outpath)
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|', header=None, chunksize=10**6):
        chunk = chunk[chunk[0].str.match('^ab[\s\S]*?cd')]
        chunk[0].to_csv(outpath, index=False, header=False, mode='a')

newsearch('list.txt')
```

**A dask approach**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

def newsearch(filename):
    chunk = dd.read_csv(filename, header=None, blocksize=25e6)
    chunk = chunk[chunk[0].str.match('^ab[\s\S]*?cd')]
    chunk[0].to_csv('output.txt', index=False, header=False, single_file = True)

newsearch('list.txt')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214222/discussion-on-answer-by-bertil-johannes-ipsen-memoryerror-in-python-by-searching).

Answer (score 2):

You are doing line by line processing so you want to avoid accumulating data in memory. Regular file reads and writes should work well here. `mmap` is backed by virtual memory, but that has to turn into real memory as you read it. Accumulating results in `findall` is also a memory hog. Try this as an alternate:

```
import re

# buffer to 1Meg but any effect would be modest
MEG = 2**20

def searchFile(filename, raw_str):
    # extract start and end from "ab***cd"
    startswith, endswith = re.match(r"([^\*]+)\*+?([^\*]+)", raw_str).groups()
    with open(filename, buffering=MEG) as in_f, open("results.txt", "w", buffering=MEG) as out_f:
        for line in in_f:
            stripped = line.strip()
            if stripped.startswith(startswith) and stripped.endswith(endswith):
                out_f.write(line)

# write test file

test_txt = """ab12345cd
abbbcd
ab_fghfghfghcd
1abcd
agcd
bb111cd
"""

want = """ab12345cd
abbbcd
ab_fghfghfghcd
"""

open("test.txt", "w").write(test_txt)

searchFile("test.txt", "ab**cd")

result = open("results.txt").read()
print(result == want)
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. Just so I understand this, you're not using regex in the overall search, you're just looking at the start character and end character of each line? If they match the input string `ab**cd`, it writes to file? Sorry bit confused here apologies

Comment: @TomOldy - I may have misunderstood the problem, but I took it that you have start and end strings separated by asterics, and you want to find strings in the dataset that have these same start and end strings. So I used regex to get them and then switched to a simpler check whether the target strings start and end with those discovered strings.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what advantage you believe you will get from opening the input file with `mmap`, but since each string that must be matched is delimited by a newline (as per your comment), I would use the below approach (Note that it is Python, but deliberately kept as pseudo code):

```py
with open(input_file_path, "r") as input_file:
  with open(output_file_path, "x" as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
      if is_match(line):
        print(line, file=output_file)
```

possibly tuning the `endline` parameter of the `print` function to your needs.

This way results are written as they are generated, and you avoid having a large `results` in memory before writing it.
Furthermore, you don't need to concentrate about newlines. Only whether each line matches.

Comment: Thanks for this - how would you feed the example regular expression into this search? For example `^ab^s[\s\S]*?cd` ??

Comment: @TomOldy First, I'd probably just use `.*` instead of `[\s\S]*`, and then I dont quite get your usage of `?`. In any case, if you only ever check for starting and ending characters, I'd parse the input string and use `myString.startswith(head)` and `myString.endswith(tail)`.

Comment: @TomOldy I have updated my pseudo code to accommodate that your result always is the input line if it matches.